# Prove that if $f(x)$ is continuous in $\mathbb R$ then exists $x$ such that $f(x)f(x+1) \ge 0$

Tags: calculus

I have a homework question to prove that if $f(x)$ is continuous in $\mathbb R$ then exists $x$ such that $f(x)f(x+1) \ge 0$.

I am failing to see why this is true and how I can prove this.

Can someone please help me out? Thanks :)

Comment: When I started thinking of a counter example it became clear to me :) but thanks for the help anyways XD

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If $f(x)=0$ for some $x$, then it is trivial. Otherwise, $f>0$ or $f<0$ always, by continuity. In this case take any $x$.

**Addendum**: the continuity assumption cannot be lifted; for example, take $f(x)=(-1)^{\lfloor x \rfloor}$.

**Addendum #2**: the example of $f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$ shows that it is possible for the set of $x$'s satisfying the requirement to have zero measure (although it is always at least countably infinite).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have that
/The product is negative
/For some $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Then the signs of both
/Pieces of product above
/Can not be the same.

Then by IVT/For this $x$ and $x+1$/Root lies in-between.

Let that root be $r$/Product at $r$,$r+1$/Zero, QED.

Comment: This haiku answer/cannot be complete without/[this xkcd](http://xkcd.com/622/).